# /ptregs in syscall table

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

Why some syscalls in the syscall table have `/ptregs`?

example from [arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl):

```
54      64      setsockopt              sys_setsockopt
55      64      getsockopt              sys_getsockopt
56      common  clone                   sys_clone/ptregs
57      common  fork                    sys_fork/ptregs
58      common  vfork                   sys_vfork/ptregs
59      64      execve                  sys_execve/ptregs
60      common  exit                    sys_exit
61      common  wait4                   sys_wait4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are special system calls which require full register dump laid out on the stack (as a `struct pt_regs`). This is a thing only for the 64-bit x86 architecture because it has more registers (compared to 32-bit).

The system call handler ([arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:entry_SYSCALL_64](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L153)) saves most of the registers on the stack on system call entry. This is done partially to support ptrace() and partially to pass the arguments to actual system call handlers written in C (this is why they have `asmlinkage` spec, its makes the function get arguments from stack). System calls have at most 6 arguments (rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9), and some registers are used for SYSCALL bookkeeping (rax, rcx, r11). You do not need to save rbp, rbx, r12, r13, r14, r15 (as they are callee-saved), so they are not saved on entry for performance reasons. After the system call handling completes the registers are restored from this backup before returning to userspace.

However, some system calls (like execve(), fork(), sigreturn(), etc.) need to have *all* registers on the stack (including rbp, rbx, r12–r15), in the `struct pt_regs`. This is because these system calls can cause the userspace to restart execution from a different place, so they need accurate register values saved. They are marked with `/ptregs` in syscall_64.tbl so that the following magic happens.

Normally the system call handler table (`sys_call_table`) contains pointers to C functions. But for those special system calls the handlers are [small assembly thunks](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L356) which first save the extra registers and then jump to the C code (this is what the slow-path does). The `/ptregs` suffix in the table instructs the script to insert these stubs instead of C functions into the handler table.